# Dynamically pass parameters (including complex expressions) to update clause using DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb, dynamicparameters

How can I dynamically pass parameters to clause after set in DolphinDB? For example, `update quote set fname = ufunc(k)`, where `fname` is a variable `ufunc` is a custom function, and k is an external variable. How should I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following example, use function `sqlUpdate` with `sqlColAlias`. More examples can be found in the link below about
[Meta programming](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Objects/Metaprogramming.html).

```
t1=table(`A`A`B`B as symbol, 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 as date, 12 13 21 22 as price)
b = `price
c = t1.price
def ufunc(b){
   return b+1}
sqlUpdate(t1, sqlColAlias(makeCall(ufunc, c), b)).eval()
t1
```